# Reactive data with ROSE resampling technique in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make a shiny apps that can show about resampling technique in ROSE package. But the problem is the ROSE function can't find function of my reactive data. this is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ROSE)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "mydata",
                label = "Select data:",
                choices = c("iris", "co2", "women")),
    uiOutput('select_y'),
    DTOutput("data_table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydatax <- reactive(
    switch (input$mydata,
      "iris" = iris,
      "co2" = CO2,
      "women" = women
    )
  )
  
  output$select_y <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "varY",
                label = "Choose VI:",
                choices = names(mydatax()))
  })
  
  myresample <- reactive({
    ROSE(input$varY~., data = mydata(), seed = 12)
  })

  output$data_table <- renderDT(
    myresample()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
`
```

and this is the error massage : `Error in mydata: could not find function "mydata"`.
please, can anyone tell me what a mistake I did?

btw, sorry about my English skill

correction:

```
myresample <- reactive({
    ROSE(input$varY~., data = mydatax(), seed = 12)
  })
```

and I get another error message: `Error in eval: object 'input' not found`

Comment: Your reactive that returns your data is `mydatax`, not `mydata`.

Comment: oh my,, thank's Limely, I'm sorry about that. now i use `mydatax` and get another error: `Error in eval: object 'input' not found`. Why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myresample <- reactive({
  f <- paste0(input$varY, " ~ .")
  ROSE(as.formula(f), data = mydata(), seed = 12)
})
```

Comment: Great. Thank's @stéphane-laurent